# CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 requested, with a size of 1

Tags: java, android, exception

I'm creating an app which stores diary entries. Upon retrieving the diary entry I get a `CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException`, I believe it is something to do with my `SELECT` statement to get the information within the DB.

```
    getDAO = new DAO(this);
    Cursor showDiaryEntries = getDAO.queryDiary(Diary.DiaryItem.FULL_PROJECTION, Diary.DiaryItem.COLUMN_NAME_DIARY_TITLE+" = "+fieldTitle, null);


    Long fieldDate = showDiaryEntries.getLong(1);
    Long fieldTime = showDiaryEntries.getLong(2);
    String fieldEntry = showDiaryEntries.getString(3);

    mDate.setText(String.valueOf(fieldDate));
    Log.i(TAG,"Field Date "+ fieldDate);
    mTime.setText(String.valueOf(fieldTime));
    Log.i(TAG,"Field Time "+ fieldTime);
    mEntry.setText(fieldEntry);
    Log.i(TAG,"Field Entry "+ fieldEntry);
```

I've been reading about this type of exception and believe it may be to do with when I getting the String/Long as I don't have a loop? Although I don't fully comprehend this.

**Log Cat**

```
03-07 07:10:59.475: E/AndroidRuntime(1471): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-07 07:10:59.475: E/AndroidRuntime(1471): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.democo.mydiary/com.democo.mydiary.DiaryEntryActivity}: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 requested, with a size of 1
```

I was hoping someone would be able to educate me as to what the problem is.
Thanks

Comment: Call `moveToFirst()` on the `Cursor` before getting the values from it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

first make sure your cursor is

*`not null`

*`Then move it to first position`

```
if(showDiaryEntries!=null &&  showDiaryEntries.moveToFirst())
{
//Now do waht ever u want to do with cursor
 }
```

Above code will take care of problem you are facing now and also which you may face in future.

Comment: Thank you! I originally used showDiaryEntries.moveToFirst BUT I encountered a problem when there wasn't any entries but I wanted to add one as it was looking for data which wasn't existent within the database. This helped me. Thanks

Comment: using both `showDiaryEntries.getCount>0 && showDiaryEntries.moveToFirst()` is redudant internaly `moveToFirst()` calls `moveToPosition(0)`, which returns `getCount()>position;`

Comment: @Selvin yes u r right i edited may ans..Thanks for pointing it out

Comment: Is that not supposed to beshowDiaryEntries!=null..etc..?

Comment: @ChristopheHarris thanks bro..I corrected my answer. Happy Coding!!

Answer (score 7):

Make sure you call:

```
showDiaryEntries.moveToFirst();
```

Do this before you start doing anything to the cursor. This will make sure the cursor starts at the FIRST row in the database!

Answer (score 2):

When you fill a cursor, it is positioned BEFORE the first record (which index is 0); now your cursor index is -1, which corresponds to no record position.

Therefore you get an error (You try to get the values from the columns of no row).

This s why you should always moveToFirst your cursor before starting to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Following code is to used for how to get cursor value.

```
Cursor showDiaryEntries= dbh.database_function();
if (showDiaryEntries.getCount() != 0 && showDiaryEntries!=null) {
    if (showDiaryEntries.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            fieldEntry  = showDiaryEntries.getString(showDiaryEntries.getColumnIndex("database feild name here"));

        } while (showDiaryEntries.moveToNext());

    }
}
```

i am providing string for an example. so update your function with your long and string field..